# Como utilizar JWT Bearer como forma de autenticação para APIs e Identity para autenticar as paginas MVC no mesmo projeto

Tags: asp.net-core

É possível no mesmo projeto ter uma API com os endpoints protegidos pelo JWT Bearer e as paginas web MVC protegidas pelo identity? Já tenho o MVC funcionando perfeitamente com Identity, porém quando habilito a autenticação JWT, ele para de funcionar. Vi algumas documentações da microsoft, porém sem sucesso na implementação.

Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Lembrando que estou utilizando o asp.net core 2.2